# How to get Youtube Channel Name using querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, selectors-api

[OUTPUT : Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss1f1.png)

**URL :** https://www.youtube.com/feed/trending?gl=IN

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string"]')[0].innerText;

document.querySelectorAll('a[class="yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-formatted-string"]')[1].innerText;
```

**QUESTION :** Why are there duplicates in OUTPUT on the Console (click on the image above)? Can someone explain what is happening here? How to retreive ***Unique Channel Name?***

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#meta a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.yt-formatted-string')[1].innerText;
```

There is another hidden element within a < div > with the id of 'channel-info' with the same set of classes. You can press F12 then CTRL-F to search for that set of classes to see the duplicate.